# Sum If in Power Query

Tags: excel, powerbi, powerquery, sumifs, m

How can I sum a column if the value is less than a certain value and matches another value.

[image: Example Data]

I have put this together in Excel but now need to replicate it in Power Query. The Opening Stock Column is what I am trying to achieve. In Excel the formula in Cell D3 down is

```
=SUMIFS(B:B,C:C,"<"&C3,A:A,A3)
```

So basically I want to sum Column B if column C is less than the current value in column C and if Column A matches the current value in column A

How is this written in Power Query

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Simon

Comment: Welcome to SO! SO it is not a free coding service. What did you try?

Comment: You are looking to apply an Earlier function in Power Query, can this be moved to DAX?

Answer (score 1):

In M (Power Query) you have to add a column with your condition (Your conditions doesnt make sense so I used just an example). Go to `Add Column > Custom Column` and use the following expression:

```
'Name of new column: Column D
= if [Column C] < [Column B] and [Column A] = [Column B] then [Column B] else null
```

So basically I write the value of `Column B` in a new cell if the condition is statisfied.
Now when you go back to your report and put a chart into it, you can drag and drop `Column D` into your chart and use as aggregate `Sum`.